# Hide a Facebook tab, but preserve the url

Tags: facebook, iframe

I have a question about hiding Facebook tabs but preserving the url of the app on the page.

So for example I add an app to the page and it shows up in the tabs menu. I then remove the app but I want the url which was created to access the app to still work.

At the moment when I do this the url just points to the Facebook page.

Would this require some code adding to the app?

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible. These are internal mechanism of Facebook, and you can’t do anything to achieve that inside of your app, because your app does not even get “called” by Facebook in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will look into other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible - it's not possible to have a 'hidden' tab which can still be linked to - if the user can access the tab, it appears in the list of tabs for that page.

Two options:

1. Run the content in a canvas app and link there from the page.
2. Host different content in an existing tab which only appears when directly linked to (via the `app_data` parameter described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/